# Compute the value of a series of integrals taking values in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

I have a question regarding this post that I wrote some time ago:

[Question about a proof regarding the spectral radius of a linear bounded operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3569304)

At the end of the question I wrote that:

*by continuity of the Riemann integral with values in $L(E)$, $$ \int_{0} ^{2\pi}t^{p+1}e^{i(p+1)\theta}R(e^{i \theta}, T)d \theta = \\\sum_{n} \int_{0}^{2\pi} t^{p-n} e^{i(p-n) \theta}T^n d \theta = 2\pi T^p. $$*

Rereading the post, I really don't get why the last equality holds. Why does the sum of those integrals equals $2\pi T^p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral itself is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(p-n)\theta}\,d\theta=\begin{cases}2\pi,&\ n=p\\[0.3cm] 0,&\ n\ne p\end{cases}
$$
as the rest does not depend on $\theta$.
So the expression is
$$
2\pi\,t^{0}\,T^p=2\pi\,T^p. 
$$